# Delete last comma from xml file using shell xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, bash, shell, xmlstarlet

I've got `comp.xml` file which contains

```
<project name="installer" >
<property name="workflow.list" >
 BTCH.WF_BatchRequest_Process.BatchRating,
 BTCH.WF_BatchRequest_Process.Invoice,
</property>
<property name="wfGroup.list" >
BTCH.WFG_BatchResPrep,
BTCH.WFG_BatchRes,
</property>
<target name="shutdown">
<echo>shutdown</echo>    
</target>  
</project>
```

I need to delete last ',' comma in each `<property>` tag **using shell** if that comma exists
So it should be:

```
<project name="installer" >
<property name="workflow.list" >
BTCH.WF_BatchRequest_Process.BatchRating,
BTCH.WF_BatchRequest_Process.Invoice
</property>
<property name="wfGroup.list" >
BTCH.WFG_BatchResPrep,
BTCH.WFG_BatchRes
</property>
<target name="shutdown">
<echo>shutdown</echo>    
</target>  
</project>
```

Comment: `awk -v RS="</property>" '{sub(",$","",$NF)} {print $0,RS}' file` makes it, but breaks the format.

Comment: My file is much more bigger... it looks terrible without formatting :(

Comment: I've found a solution. Hardcode, but it works in my case...

`sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/,\n</\n</g'`

Thanx for help!

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the property value will always end in `<comma><newline>` then the following xslt works for me (on your sample data at least).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="property">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(text(), 1, string-length(text()) - 2)"/><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Most of the above is simply the [identity transformation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying). The rest is just a match on the `property` elements and a small amount of text manipulation.

Comment: Can you recommend a book or ?? that will shed this level of enlightenment of using xslt? I realize this is off-purpose for S.O. so "no" is an acceptable answer too :-) Good luck to all.